# ImportError: No module named util.dtree_util

Tags: python, import, module

I get this error when loading a file using cPickle.

Directory tree:

```
/qanta/preprocess/dparse_to_dtree.py
/qanta/qanta.py
/qanta/util/dtree_util.py
main.py
extract_data.py
```

main.py imports extract_data.py

extract_data.py imports dparse_to_dtree.py

A function in dparse_to_dtree.py cPickle dumps a dtree object which is defined in dtree_util.py

then from Main.py a subprocess calls qanta.py to execute but there I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "qanta/qanta.py", line 142, in <module>
cPickle.load(open(args['data'], 'rb'))
ImportError: No module named util.dtree_util
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add a `__init__.py` file. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) question.

Comment: it's present in all folders

Answer (score 0):

Not very nice but adding

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./qanta/util')
```

and importing with from ... import * solved the problem